# XWayland applications with black flickering

Tags: arch-linux, x11, nvidia, wayland, sway

Currently on my computer I have ArchLinux with sway-nvidia + nvidia-lts. With 2 monitors (1080p 144hz and 1080p 60hz) The wayland applications work perfectly (Chrome, vkube, alacritty, etc) but the X11 ones I have a graphic problem (xeyes, gparted, vmware-workstation, gimp, etc).

I attach this folder where there are 2 videos where you can see these failures. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ji9GX3T1l4upFsrn4ErI4LMMrOaqXNpc?usp=share_link

I have tried to look for information and solutions but nothing I have tried seems to work.

Change environment variables such as XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
Change xorg.conf configuration
Using a single monitor
Using sway-git and wlroots-git

Comment: Wayland has known issues with NVIDIA. If you are a real fan of it you can't live without it, you'll have to migrate to open source Intel/AMD GPUs.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Experiencing exactly the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Koba 
I did not find a solution for the proprietary drivers.
I have ended up using the nouveau ones that although they are not to my liking, I can use xWayland applications.